# Two Way Binding in angular 2

Tags: angular

**Json Object**

This is the Json Object i am getting back from the service,i am unable to do a two way binding with the html.

[image: Json Response object]

**Html**
This the markup, i am unable to do the two way binding ,and i see the below error

```html
<form [formGroup]="Form">
                    <div class="form-group" ngClass="{ 'has-error': Form.controls.category_name.dirty && Form.controls.category_name.errors }">
                        <label for="category_name">Category Name</label>
                        <input formControlName="category_name" type="text" name="category_name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="categoriesInfo.CategoryName" />
                        <p *ngIf="Form.controls.category_name.errors && Form.controls.category_name.dirty">Category Name is required!</p>

                    </div>
                </form>
```

**Error Information**

this is the error i am getting when i try to bind it to html,can you please tell me how to fix this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely a async problem. View is (probably) rendered before data has arrived. Wrap your code with with an if e.g within the form tag:

```
<form *ngIf="categoriesInfo" [formGroup]="Form">
```

And BTW, you have a error that has occured when posting your question (??), since the following do not match:

```
*ngIf="Form.controls.category_name.errors && gameForm.controls.category_name.dirty"
```

meaning the `gameForm`.

Comment: when i am trying to use elvis operator i am getting this Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 30 in [categoriesInfo?.CategoryName=$event] in GamesComponent@18:117 ("       <input formControlName="category_name" type="text" name="category_name" class="form-control" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="categoriesInfo?.CategoryName" />
                        <p *ngIf="gameForm.controls.ca"): GamesComponent@18:117
Empty expressions are not allowed ("       <input formCon error, can you tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Oh sorry, I messed up myself. You cannot use ? in ngModel, only in view. Sorry, my brain has been somewhere else. Wrap the form in *ngIf instead, like at the top of my answer. ? operator can only be used in the view, like `{{categoriesInfo?.CategoryName}}` Sorry about that, will edit my answer!